# subset Armadillo field

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

If I understand correctly, a field in `Armadillo` is like a List for arbitrary objects. For instance a set of matrices of different sizes, or matrices and vectors. In the documentation I have seen the type `cube` which can be used with `slices` so you can subset using them. However, it seems there is no specific method to subset the fields.

A simplified version of my code is:

```
arma::mat A = eye(2,2);
arma::mat B = eye(3,3)*3;
arma::mat C = eye(4,4)*4;
arma::field<arma::mat> F(3,1);
F(0,0) = A;
F(1,0) = B;
F(2,1) = C;

// to get matrices B and C
F.slices(1,2);
```

but get error

`Error: field::slices(): indicies out of bounds or incorrectly used`

Comment: In addition the answer below by johanmaack, it may help to think of the `.slices()` function as specifying the z-axis, while the `.cols()` and `.rows()`  functions as specifying the x-axis and y-axis, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, there is a small error in the code you presented:

```
F(2,1) = C;
```

I assume it should be:

```
F(2,0) = C;
```

Secondly, the function slices() is only valid for 3D fields. Your field F, however, is only a 2D field because you only specify rows and columns in the constructor. To access matrices B and C, you can instead use:

```
arma::field<arma::mat> G=F.subfield(1,0,2,0);
```

or:

```
arma::field<arma::mat> G=F.rows(1,2);
```

More info on the subfield views at [this page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subfield).